# Detect content uncompatible with adsense

Tags: python, forum, adsense, user-generated-content

For a website that contains user generated content and that cannot be moderated before publishing, is there a way (python API, stop words database etc...) to detect the page content is OK for adense ?
(In my case, I am publishing realtime statistics about twitter hashtags, and unfortunately, some hastags are considerated as adult content for adsense)